# How can i get keys based on values in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this object

`{'a': 'test1', 'b': 'test2', 'c': 'test3'}`

Then i have

`[{name: 'test1', selected: true}, {name: 'test3', selected: true}]`

Now i want to get final list of keys whose selected is true in second object

```
['a', 'c']
```

How can i do that in underscore

I tried this

```
var inv_obj = _.invert(obj);

                            return _

                                .filter(objectList, function (obj) {
                                    return obj.selected
                                })
                                .map(function (obj, inv_obj) {
                                    return inv_obj[obj] ?:''
                                })
```

Comment: show us some code, what did you try? what did not work in your code?

Comment: `inv_obj[obj] ?:''` this seems like a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var a={'a': 'test1', 'b': 'test2', 'c': 'test3'};
var b=[{name: 'test1', selected: true}, {name: 'test3', selected: true}];

var c=_.pluck(_.where(b, {selected: true}), 'name');
// ['test1', 'test3']

var d=_.invert(a);
console.log(_.values(_.pick(d, c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {'a': 'test1', 'b': 'test2', 'c': 'test3'};
var col = [{name: 'test1', selected: true}, {name: 'test2', selected: false}, {name: 'test3', selected: true}];

var inv_obj = _.invert(obj);

var final = _.filter(col, function(obj) {
    return obj.selected;
}).map(function (obj) {
    return inv_obj[obj.name];
});

console.log(final);
```